# You are trying to use "scss". node-sass is missing

Tags: node-sass, vue-cli-4, dart-sass, vue-jest

My project is running node-sass but I decided to change that to sass (dart-sass) because I want to avoid installing python, g++ and make just to run npm install, which node-sass forces you to do because of node-gyp.

So I ran

```sh
$ npm uninstall node-sass
$ npm install sass
```

Running `npm run build` (`vue-cli-service build`) works fine, but my continuous integration failed on `npm run test:unit` (`vue-cli-service test:unit`).

Here's the full error:

```
 FAIL  tests/unit/example.spec.ts
● Test suite failed to run[vue-jest] 
Error: You are trying to use "scss". node-sass is missing.

    To install run:  
npm install --save-dev node-sass
at error (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/throw-error.js:2:9)
at module.exports (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/ensure-require.js:38:5)                                                                                                                                                                     at module.exports (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/compilers/scss-compiler.js:20:3)
at processStyleByLang (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/process-style.js:11:82)
at processStyle (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/process-style.js:20:17)
at node_modules/vue-jest/lib/process.js:93:13
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Object.module.exports [as process] (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/process.js:90:8)
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.265s, estimated 2s
```

What do I do to fix this error? I don't want to go back to node-sass.

Comment: Note to copy-pasters, it looks like the code snippet above has an error. `experimentalCSSCompilation` should be `experimentalCSSCompile` (as stated in the second part of the answer).

Comment: Looks like the moderator moved your comment to the question, whereas you meant to comment on the response :|

Answer (score 6):

I think this error is happening because `vue-jest` is trying to compile CSS in unit tests. The `sass` (`dart-sass`) package doesn't have this feature, but `node-sass` does.

A quick fix **at the cost of having style compilation in unit tests** is to prevent vue-jest from compiling styles:

```json
//package.json `"jest":` property or jest.config.js `module.exports = `
{
  "globals": {
     "vue-jest": {
       "experimentalCSSCompile": false
      }
   }
}
```

I'm using `vue-jest@3.0.7`

[From vue-jest docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/blob/851d16cce049db5b9a190e616d3ffdd96127118f/README.md#css-options):

> experimentalCSSCompile:
> Boolean Default true.
> Turn off CSS compilation

[I also found this japanese blog post (automatically translated here)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://qiita.com/mascii/items/6fd5333b65931b55d38b) that details this error

A side effect of this is that unit tests now run much faster